# Defining python global variable in sub function

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, global-variables

I have a Tkinter gui that opens a separate gui with checkboxes. In this separate window, I need to reference the states of the checkboxes, but I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\@ Batch\LMS Python Script\tester3.pyw", line 23, in var_states
    print("FX: %d, FY: %d, FZ: %d, MX: %d, MY: %d, MZ: %d" % (FX_1.get(), FY_1.get(), FZ_1.get(),MX_1.get(), MY_1.get(), MZ_1.get()))
NameError: global name 'FX_1' is not defined
```

Is it possible to define and reference a global variable from a sub function?

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tempfile

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Generate APDL")
root.geometry("200x225")

Lbl1 = Label(root, text="How many interface points?")
Lbl1.pack(side=TOP,padx=5,pady=5)
Entry1 = Entry(root, bd =1)
Entry1.pack(side=TOP,padx=5,pady=5)

def NewWindow():

    IPoints=int(Entry1.get())
    NumPoints=IPoints+1

    master = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    master.title("Select Unit Load Components")

    def var_states():
        print("FX: %d, FY: %d, FZ: %d, MX: %d, MY: %d, MZ: %d" % (FX_1.get(), FY_1.get(), FZ_1.get(),MX_1.get(), MY_1.get(), MZ_1.get()))

    def CloseWindow():
        master.destroy()

    for i in xrange(1,NumPoints):

        Label(master, text="PT_%d: " % i).grid(row=i,column=0, sticky=W)
        exec('global FX_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
        Checkbutton(master, text="FX", variable='FX_%d' % i).grid(row=i,column=2, sticky=W)
        exec('global FY_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
        Checkbutton(master, text="FY", variable='FY_%d' % i).grid(row=i,column=3, sticky=W)
        exec('global FZ_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
        Checkbutton(master, text="FZ", variable='FZ_%d' % i).grid(row=i,column=4, sticky=W)
        exec('global MX_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
        Checkbutton(master, text="MX", variable='MX_%d' % i).grid(row=i,column=5, sticky=W)
        exec('global MY_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
        Checkbutton(master, text="MY", variable='MY_%d' % i).grid(row=i,column=6, sticky=W)
        exec('global MZ_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
        Checkbutton(master, text="MZ", variable='MZ_%d' % i).grid(row=i,column=7, sticky=W)


    Label(master, text=" ").grid(row=99,column=0, sticky=W)
    Bttn1=Button(master, text='Generate APDL Snippet', command=var_states).grid(row=100,column=0, sticky=W)
    Label(master, text=" ").grid(row=101,column=0, sticky=W)
    Bttn2=Button(master, text='Close Window', command=CloseWindow)
    Bttn2.grid(row=102,column=0, sticky=W)

Bttn1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="Open New Window", command = NewWindow)
Bttn1.pack(side = TOP,padx=10,pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback of your error, it provides a lot more detail that we can use to help answer.

Comment: Also why do you `from Tkinter import *` and `import Tkinter`, this seems like an obvious redundancy

Comment: What are you doing with exec?

Comment: I am trying to define global variables based on the index of the for loop, so if I loop through i=1 to 10, I should have global variables FX_1, FX_2, FX_3... etc. The exec command allows me to embed the current index number of the for loop into the variable name.

Comment: Yes, I know the imports are redundant... I just didn't remove them before posting.

Comment: You should not be using variables named `FX_1` *et al*, you should be using a list.

Comment: @kindall: a list, or a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

This little hack that you're trying to pull with `global` is something I've never seen before -- Kudos for originality :-), but I wouldn't suggest that you keep going down that road because it's going to be a major pain to get it to work (if it's even possible) and in the long-run maintenance will be even more painful.

Never fear though.  There *is* a better way!  Generally in these circumstances, I recommend using a `class`.  With a class, you can carry all of the state that you need along with `self`.  Here's an abbreviated version of your code:

```
class NewWindowFactory(object):
    def var_states(self):
        print 'FX_1', self.FX_1.get()
    def NewWindow(self):
        for i in xrange(1,NumPoints):
            label = Label(master, text="PT_%d: " % i)
            label.grid(row=i,column=0, sticky=W)
            setattr(self, 'FX_' + str(i), label)
        Button(master, text='Generate APDL Snippet', command=self.var_states).grid(row=100,column=0, sticky=W)
```

Usage would look something like this:

```
factory = NewWindowFactory()
Bttn1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Open New Window", command = factory.NewWindow)
Bttn1.pack(side = TOP,padx=10,pady=5)
```

---

Also note that whenever you have a series of variables `Foo1`, `Foo2`, `Foo3` ..., you generally want to start thinking about using a different data structure (in this case, you probably actually want a list of checkboxes rather than 10 checkbox variables).  For a more in-depth explanation, see [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html), an execellent article by Ned Batchelder.

An astute reader might notice that there are benefits to be gained by turning the *entire* application into a class (you can set up the initial UI in `__init__`).  I would definitely recommend that approach, but I didn't write it out to keep this suggestion as simple as possible.

Comment: I cant see how to define the FX_1 variable based on a check box state in your example. Could your clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the original code to work. I had to global declarations in the wrong spot... I also had to define the variable first in the main loop. I know there is a more elegant way to do this, but it works.

```
    for i in xrange(1,100):
        exec('var1_' + str(i) + ' = Tkinter.IntVar()')
        exec('var2_' + str(i) + ' = Tkinter.IntVar()')
        exec('var3_' + str(i) + ' = Tkinter.IntVar()')
        exec('var4_' + str(i) + ' = Tkinter.IntVar()')
        exec('var5_' + str(i) + ' = Tkinter.IntVar()')
        exec('var6_' + str(i) + ' = Tkinter.IntVar()')

    def NewWindow():
        IPoints=int(Entry1.get())
        NumPoints=IPoints+1
        MaxComp=IPoints*6

        master = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        master.title("Select Unit Load Components")

        Label(master, text="Interface Points        ").grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text="FX").grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text="FY").grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text="FZ").grid(row=0,column=3, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text="MX").grid(row=0,column=4, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text="MY").grid(row=0,column=5, sticky=W)
        Label(master, text="MZ").grid(row=0,column=6, sticky=W)

        def var_states():
            exec('global var1_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
            exec('global var2_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
            exec('global var3_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
            exec('global var4_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
            exec('global var5_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()
            exec('global var6_' + str(i)) in globals(), locals()

            print("FX: %d, FY: %d, FZ: %d, MX: %d, MY: %d, MZ: %d" % (var1_15.get(), var2_15.get(), var3_15.get(),var4_15.get(), var5_15.get(), var6_15.get()))

        for i in xrange(1,NumPoints):
            Label(master, text="PT_%d: " % i).grid(row=i,column=0, sticky=W)
            exec('Checkbutton(master, text="  ", variable=var1_' + str(i) + ').grid(row=i,column=1, sticky=W)') in globals(), locals()
            exec('Checkbutton(master, text="  ", variable=var2_' + str(i) + ').grid(row=i,column=2, sticky=W)') in globals(), locals()
            exec('Checkbutton(master, text="  ", variable=var3_' + str(i) + ').grid(row=i,column=3, sticky=W)') in globals(), locals()
            exec('Checkbutton(master, text="  ", variable=var4_' + str(i) + ').grid(row=i,column=4, sticky=W)') in globals(), locals()
            exec('Checkbutton(master, text="  ", variable=var5_' + str(i) + ').grid(row=i,column=5, sticky=W)') in globals(), locals()
            exec('Checkbutton(master, text="  ", variable=var6_' + str(i) + ').grid(row=i,column=6, sticky=W)') in globals(), locals()


        Button(master, text='Show', command=var_states).grid(row=100, sticky=W, pady=4)
```